# If an Echo Knight fighter has a bow equipped, can they make an opportunity attack from the echo's space with a dagger, then use the bow on their turn?

Tags: dnd-5e, weapons, opportunity-attack, fighter, echo-knight

One of my players is playing a level 5 Echo Knight fighter with the Thrown Weapon Fighting fighting style. Their primary source of damage is their bow. However, they utilize the ability to draw a weapon with the thrown property as part of the attack to make opportunity attacks with their Echo.

When the Echo Knight has their primary weapon (a bow) equipped, can they still use their reaction for an opportunity attack from the Echo's location using a dagger hidden somewhere on their body, and then on their own turn still use their bow as normal?

Comment: Hi Bamischijf! Welcome to RPG.SE! You might want to take the [tour](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tour) if you haven't already, and check out the [help center](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help) for more guidance.

Comment: I have added the [dnd-5e] tag to your question. If your question isn't about Dungeons and Dragons 5th Edition, please indicate the correct game. Thanks.

Comment: Do your interpretations not make it clear whether thrown weapons include arrows "thrown" from bows?

To me it's clear arrows are not "thrown" as axes, maces, spears or even swords might be… and I accept that's about technique, if not technology.

Do you see it differently?

Comment: What makes you think that a weapon can be thrown as part of an opportunity attack (with or without the Thrown Weapon Fighting fighting style)? ...Or are you merely claiming that they're taking advantage of the fighting style's ability to draw the weapon (and even if it's not a ranged attack)? That wasn't clear to me when I first read the question.

Comment: It seems like it may be worth asking a separate question about that part of this post (e.g. "If you have the Thrown Weapon Fighting fighting style, can you draw a weapon with the thrown property as part of the attack you make with it, even if you're not throwing it?"). The rest of your current question relies on the answer to that being "yes", since you can't normally draw a weapon outside of your turn without something like that fighting style.

Comment: Apologies if I was unclear. My question is whether it is possible to draw a dagger as part of a melee opportunity attack due to access to the Thrown Weapon Mastery fighting style. 
This would allow the Echo Knight character to stab the target with their reaction from the position of the echo (placed adjacent to the target). The real character would then be able to stand out of melee range, and continue firing their bow.

Edit: I just noticed you've taken the liberty to change the title of the question. I specified there that my question was regarding a melee opportunity attack.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Rules-as-written, looks like yes.

I'm not sure that it matters that the character is an Echo Knight; the same question would arise for any player with a two-handed ranged weapon and the Thrown Weapon fighting style.

Relevant rules excerpts and references:

Two-handed weapons: PHB, p147

> *This weapon requires two hands* **when you attack with it** (emphasis mine)

Thrown Weapon Fighting: TCoE, p42

> *You can draw a weapon that has the thrown property as part of the attack you make with the weapon* [no mention that the attack has to be ranged]

Other Activity on Your Turn: PHB, p190. Drawing or sheathing a weapon is explicitly mentioned as something you can do in addition to your action (which is relevant for putting the weapon away before attacking with the bow again).

Opportunity Attacks: PHB, p195:

> *you use your reaction to make one melee attack against the provoking creature*.

It's not specified anywhere that you need to currently be wielding a melee weapon in order to make that attack, just that the attack itself is not ranged.

So, you don't need to hold a bow with two hands when not attacking with it (i.e. outside of your turn), you can draw a weapon with the thrown property as part of an attack whether you're throwing it or not, and you can sheathe the weapon again on your turn before attacking with a bow.